# Different styles for different input files for acro package

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, nomenclature, acro

I am writing a document with acro package for list of acronyms and nomenclatures. I have abbreviations defined in file `Abbrev.tex` and nomenclatures defined in file `Nomen.tex`. I import these files using `\input`. Is it possible to have separate styles for defined acronyms in two files? I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{acro} %list of abbreviations
\acsetup{first-style=long-short,list/display = used}
\input{Abbrev.tex} %define abbreviations in this file.
\acsetup{first-style=short,list/display = used}
\input{Nomen.tex} %define nomenclature in this file.

\begin{document}
\ac{afm} is a good technique.
\newline
\ac{L} is used in the calculation.
\end{document}
```

**Abbrev.tex**

```
\DeclareAcronym{afm}{ 
    short = {AFM}, 
    long  = {Atomic Force Microscopy},
    tag = {abbrev}
}
\DeclareAcronym{ofet}{
    short = {OFET},
    long  = {Organic field effect transistor},
    tag = {abbrev}
}
```

**Nomen.tex**

```
\DeclareAcronym{A}{ 
    short = {A}, 
    long  = {Area},
    tag = {nomen}
}
\DeclareAcronym{L}{
    short = {L},
    long  = {Length of channel},
    tag = {nomen}
}
```

Comment: Would you please provide an example containing some abbreviations and nomenclatures we can compile? The code you've provided so far can't be used to really help.

Comment: @phil-elkabat I have added a proper mwe.

Comment: If by “separate styles” you mean different `first-style`s then your MWE is not going to work. The first style is determined the first time an acronym is used in the text and not when it is defined in the preamble. What you can do is assign a `first-style` to an acronym itself (like the `short` and `long` properties. In combination with a custom macro this might be a way to effectively define the classes of acronyms with two different first styles.

Answer (score 3):

## Acro version 3.2

Here comes an example using acro version 3.2. I have added a couple of options just so you can see what `acro` is capable of:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[version=3]{acro} %list of abbreviations
\acsetup{
    first-style = long,
    list/display = used,
    pages/display = first
}

\DeclareAcronym{afm}{ 
    short = {AFM}, 
    long  = {Atomic Force Microscopy},
    tag = {abbrev},
}
\DeclareAcronym{ofet}{
    short = {OFET},
    long  = {Organic field effect transistor},
    tag = {abbrev},
}

\DeclareAcronym{A}{ 
    short = {A}, 
    long  = {Area},
    tag = {nomen},
    first-style = short,
}
\DeclareAcronym{L}{
    short = {L},
    long  = {Length of channel},
    tag = {nomen},
    first-style = short,
}

\begin{document}

\section{Some of my best Abbreviations}

\ac{afm} is a good technique.
\newline
\ac{L} is used in the calculation.

\printacronyms[name=Abbreviations, include=abbrev, heading=section*]
\printacronyms[name=Nomenclature, include=nomen]

\end{document}
```

[image: acro v3.2]

## Acro version 2.1

After struggling with acro v3, I've learned that my not up-to-date TeX distribution only comes with acro v. 2.10. You should definitely check, which version you're running, first.

For version 2.1 you could do it like this:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{acro} %list of abbreviations

\DeclareAcronym{afm}{ 
    short = {AFM}, 
    long  = {Atomic Force Microscopy},
    class = {abbrev},
    first-style = long,
}
\DeclareAcronym{ofet}{
    short = {OFET},
    long  = {Organic field effect transistor},
    class = {abbrev},
    first-style = long,
}

\DeclareAcronym{A}{ 
    short = {A}, 
    long  = {Area},
    class = {nomen},
    first-style = short,
}
\DeclareAcronym{L}{
    short = {L},
    long  = {Length of channel},
    class = {nomen},
    first-style = short,
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some of my best Abbreviations}

\ac{afm} is a good technique.
\newline
\ac{L} is used in the calculation.

\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]
\printacronyms[include-classes=nomen,name=Nomenclature]

\end{document}
```

[image: abbreviations]

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my comment into an answer:

If by “separate styles” you mean different `first-style`s then your MWE is not going to work. The first style is determined the first time an acronym is *used in the text* and *not when it is defined* in the preamble. What you can do is assign a `first-style` to an acronym itself (like the `short` and `long` properties). In combination with a custom macro this might be a way to effectively define the classes of acronyms with two different first styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\NewDocumentCommand\NewAbbrev{mm}{%
  \DeclareAcronym{#1}{
    #2,
    first-style=long-short,
    tag=abbrev
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\NewNomen{mm}{%
  \DeclareAcronym{#1}{
    #2,
    first-style=short,
    tag=nomen
  }%
}

\NewAbbrev{afm}{ 
  short = AFM , 
  long  = Atomic Force Microscopy
}
\NewAbbrev{ofet}{
  short = OFET ,
  long  = Organic field effect transistor
}
\NewNomen{A}{ 
  short = $A$ ,
  long  = Area
}
\NewNomen{L}{
  short = $L$ ,
  long  = Length of channel
}

\acsetup{list/display = used}

\begin{document}

\ac{afm} is a good technique. \par
\ac{L} is used in the calculation.

\printacronyms[name=Abbreviations, include=abbrev]
\printacronyms[name=Nomenclature, include=nomen]

\end{document}
```

[image]